# how to align two submit button on same line

Tags: html, css

I have a page with two submit button for different purpose,i assigned inside the table ,i am trying to align it in the same line.

html is

```
<td>
<div>
Involved: 
<form>
<input type="submit" value="Add from list">
</form>
 <p>or</p>    
<form>
<input type="submit" value="Type a name">
</form>
</div>
</td>
```

The above will produce the buttons and words in same line,i want it to be happen in same line.

seem to be like "involved    (type a name)  or   (add from list)",

may i know how to do this.

Thanks,

Comment: The number of `<div>` tags is not equal to the number of `</div>` tags, so your html is not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mess with your html, no need in that much elements

```
<td>
  <form>Involved: <input type="submit" value="Add from list"> or <input type="submit" value="Type a name"></form>
</td>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `<div>` and not tables. Give the buttons a CSS value of `display:inline-block;`

Answer (score 2):

First, you code wasn't valid because of an ending div block in the middle.

Then, **form is a block element**, that's why your browser will only display it on a new line (at least, without any style applied to it).

So what you can do is make it an inline element with the propriety *"display: inline-block"*. 
Same for you paragraph, it isn't needed, if you want to add it anyway, as it's also a block element, make sure to apply this style and make it inline.

```
<div>
Involved: 
    <form style="display:inline-block">
    <input type="submit" value="Add from list">
    </form> or      
    <form style="display:inline-block">
    <input type="submit" value="Type a name">
    </form>
</div>
```

More information on [inline vs block elements here](http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline/)

Answer (score 2):

try this css

```
div#frm *{display:inline}
```

and html

```
<div id="frm">
Involved: 
<form>
<input type="submit" value="Add from list">
</form>
 <p>or</p>    
<form>
<input type="submit" value="Type a name">
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked for me too. Btw what is the significance of `*`? I noticed that it breaks without it.

Comment: @aspiringCodingArtisan * is wild character  it will select every child tag of form

Answer (score 2):

```
<div style="display: inline;" align="center">
      <div style="float: left;">
            <button style="color: white; padding: 15px 32px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; border-radius: 4px; display: inline-block; font-size: 100%;">Hello</button>
      </div>
      <div style="float: right;">
            <button style="color: white; background-color: #4caf50; padding: 15px 32px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; border-radius: 4px; display: inline-block; font-size: 100%;">Hello</button>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
form {display: inline-block;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
<tr>
<td>
<form>
   <label>Involved:</label>
   <input type="submit" value="Add from list">
</form>  
<form>
   <label>or</label>   
   <input type="submit" value="Type a name">
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```